# Issue with Response.Redirect and Page.ResolveUrl in ASP.NET WebForms site hosted on Amazon AWS

Tags: asp.net, .net, amazon-web-services

I have deployed an ASP.NET WebForms site to Amazon AWS to the following link ('webapp' is just a dummy name I haven't included the real url)

http://webapp.elasticbeanstalk.com

My problem is that wherever I do a redirect using Response.Redirect (for example Response.Redirect('~/Page.aspx') or create a link using Page.ResolveUrl (for example Page.ResolveUrl('~/Page.aspx'), the url becomes

http://webapp.elasticbeanstalk.com/webapp_deploy/Page.aspx

But I want it to be simply:

http://webapp.elasticbeanstalk.com/Page.aspx

My guess is that the site is located in a folder called 'webapp_deploy' on the Amazon server and the home sign '~' gets mapped to 'webapp_deploy'.

Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong ? Are there any workarounds to this...do I need to change something in the AWS console ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, your web application will be deployed to webappname_deploy, but you can change that in the Project Properties.

- In the Solution Explorer, right-click on the web project and select "Properties".
- In the properties pane, go to the "Package/Publish Web" tab.
- On that tab, there is a form field labeled "IIS Web site/application name to use on the destination server:"
- Remove webappname_deploy, so it would just say "Default Web Site/"

Your web app will then be deployed to the root of the IIS Default Web Site.